# Voltage between neutral and ground

Tags: electrical-panel

I will need your help with something.
I have some strange voltages between the wires in an electrical panel in Uk (see below):

L-N = 120V
L-G = 240V
N-G = 80V

The voltage between N-G should be close to 0 but there is a voltage of 80V.
Why there is a voltage of only 120V between L and N when it should be 240V?

Thank you
Laurentiu

Comment: Is there any 3-phase power involved in this panel?

Comment: Are you using a digital voltmeter?  If you plug something simple (heater, incandescent lamp) into one of the sockets, does the problem go away?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need some more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: those numbers don't add up, that should tell you something is wrong with your measurements.

Comment: I have 2 identical stations.I am using a digital multimeter. For the first station I have performed the measurements and the results are as follows: L-N=240V; L-G=240V; N-G=0 V and the odd thing is at the 2nd station where the measurements results are not ok.